# How can I increase JS heap size of the server?

Tags: vscode-remote

I have a large C++ project and when running CMake configuration JS runs out of memory. It happened occasionally some time ago but now it is basically permanent. I found that heap size can be increased by using --max-old-space-size runtime argument, but how can I configure VSCode remote-SSH to pass it to server?

```
EXTHOST-STDOUT:::::::: <--- Last few GCs --->

[550:0x32e4190]   195337 ms: Scavenge 2017.1 (2047.9) -> 2016.5 (2048.4) MB, 2.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.222, current mu = 0.222) allocation failure [550:0x32e4190]   195341 ms: Scavenge 2017.3 (2048.4) -> 2016.8 (2048.9) MB, 2.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.222, current mu = 0.222) allocation failure [550:0x32e4190]   195345 ms: Scavenge 2017.5 (2048.9) -> 2017.0 (2049.4) MB, 2.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.222, current mu = 0.222) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x1a93942] Security context: 0x2a17c367bae1 <JSObject>
    1: split [0x3fb4f4e4c639] [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-vscode.cmake-tools-1.3.1/dist/main.js:~4925] [pc=0xcf88cdb618c](this=0x3fb4f4e49fd9 <Object map = 0x34f151bee4f9>,0x02e61934fd51 <Very long string[#39636]>,0x3394bf4b9291 <Object map = 0x34d710abc729>)
    2: next [0x2a17c36779a1](this=0x3394bf4b9241 <JSGenerator>)
    3: StubFrame [pc: 0x...


EXTHOST-STDERR::::::::FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

EXTHOST-STDERR:::::::: Writing Node.js report to file: report.20200410.102249.550.0.001.json EXTHOST-STDERR:::::::: Node.js report completed

EXTHOST-STDERR:::::::: 1: 0x98edf0 node::Abort() [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/bin/2aae1f26c72891c399f860409176fe435a154b13/node]

EXTHOST-STDERR:::::::: 2: 0x98fe56 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/bin/2aae1f26c72891c399f860409176fe435a154b13/node]

EXTHOST-STDERR:::::::: 3: 0xb1552e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/bin/2aae1f26c72891c399f860409176fe435a154b13/node]

EXTHOST-STDERR:::::::: 4: 0xb158a9 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/bin/2aae1f26c72891c399f860409176fe435a154b13/node]

EXTHOST-STDERR:::::::: 5: 0xf20105  [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/bin/2aae1f26c72891c399f860409176fe435a154b13/node]

EXTHOST-STDERR:::::::: 6: 0xf2aa6b v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/bin/2aae1f26c72891c399f860409176fe435a154b13/node]

EXTHOST-STDERR:::::::: 7: 0xf2b787 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/bin/2aae1f26c72891c399f860409176fe435a154b13/node]

EXTHOST-STDERR:::::::: 8: 0xf2e225 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/bin/2aae1f26c72891c399f860409176fe435a154b13/node]

EXTHOST-STDERR:::::::: 9: 0xef9250 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/bin/2aae1f26c72891c399f860409176fe435a154b13/node]

EXTHOST-STDERR::::::::10: 0x11cb0ce v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/bin/2aae1f26c72891c399f860409176fe435a154b13/node]

EXTHOST-STDERR::::::::11: 0x1a93942  [/home/nkarpins/.vscode-server/bin/2aae1f26c72891c399f860409176fe435a154b13/node]

[10:22:49] [127.0.0.1][df68a611][ExtensionHostConnection] <550> Extension Host Process exited with code: null, signal: SIGABRT. Cancelling previous shutdown timeout [10:22:49] Cancelling previous shutdown timeout Last EH closed, waiting before shutting down [10:22:49] Last EH closed, waiting before shutting down
```

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @NegativeZero yes, please check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution which is to set env variable in .bashrc:
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"